# select tag styling

Tags: html, select, height, line

Is there a way to style `<select>` or `<option>` tags in css? I am using a image for background for `<select>` tag, but the problem is that it is not taking line-height, so it isn't aligned towards the middle (especially in FF) vertically, and using padding makes the arrow look ugly. How would I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

`select` tags are **very** difficult to style. If fact, besides for some *very* basic styles, they are pretty much **un-style-able**.

The reason for that is that the browser is not the one drawing it. It is handled (mainly) by the OS.

If you need more control, you should replace them with Javascript. That way, they're just a bunch of divs/spans that can easily be manipulated by CSS.

The amazing [jQuery plugin called "chosen"](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) is basically built around this idea. Check it out.

Comment: This is true. Tread carefully, though, because if you use a SELECT coded entirely in JS you will end up breaking your form for users without it enabled.

Comment: But there are plenty of good example of beautiful select option.Are they done by js?

Comment: @ShaneC - The way to do it is to start out with a simple `select`. Then, if javascript is enabled, you replace it. In fact, this is how "chosen" works, but takes it a step further: even with javascript enabled, the `select` is never removed. It's still sitting there, hidden from view, firing all of its native events.

Comment: @kd7 - Yes. All of the beautiful `select`s that you see in the wild, are done using javascript. Just use firebug / web inspector on them, and you'll see a whole bunch of extra divs/spans...

Comment: @Joseph Thank you very much for information about chosen plug in.That works like magic.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give **inline style**, you will get.